# Web API POST - 404 Not Found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

In my VS2013 Web Application I have many controllers like this:

```
[Route("Test/{param1}")]
public bool Test (Int32 Param1)
{   
  return true;  
}
```

I invoke the method from my client:

```
response = await client.GetAsync("TestCtrlClass/Test/1");
```

**and all works nice**.

Now, I need to pass an object to methods, so I put this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Test2/{item}")]
public bool Test2([FromBody] ClassName item)
{
     return true;       
}
```

I invoke the method from my client:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = ServerUri;
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

MediaTypeFormatter jsonFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
HttpContent content = new ObjectContent<ClassName>(Item, jsonFormatter);
response = await client.PostAsync("TestCtrlClass/Test2", content);
```

and i get **404 NOT FOUND**.

this is my route configuration:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

**Why?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you are sending a POST request with parameters in the body. That means that the URl you are posting to is `TestCtrlClass/Test2`, not `TestCtrlClass/Test2/anything_here`. So your attribute should be:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Test2")]
public bool Test2([FromBody] ClassName item)
```

Also I believe `[FromBody]` is not needed here.